Distance between binomial and normal distributions
I want to compare binomial distribution $Bin(n,p)$ with a constant $p$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$, to a normal distribution with $\mu=np,\sigma^2=np(1-p)$.
How close are they with the discrete distribution with the pmf that is equal to the pdf at this point for a normal distribution with the same expectation and variance.
Formally, let $D_{n,p}$ be the following distribution over $\{0,\ldots,n\}$:
Let $S= \sum_{i=0}^n \phi(i)$, and let $\Pr_{X\sim D_{n,p}}[X=i] = \frac{\phi(i)}{S}$, where
$\phi(i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n p(1-p)}} e^{-\frac{(i-np)^2}{2np(1-p)}}$.
So what is the convergence of $\Delta(Bin(n,p),D_{n,p})= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n \left|\Pr_{X\sim Bin(n,p)}[X=i] - \Pr_{Y\sim D_{n,p}}[Y=i] \right|$ as $n$ goes to infinity and $p$ stays the same?

The paper Entropy and the discrete CLT should be relevant for your question.

Alternatively, using Pinsker's inequality and reducing the problem to computing $KL(Bin(n,p) \mid D_{n,p})$ seems straightforward, though I don't have time to write up the details currently.

$S$ converges to 1 exponentially fast, so you can use $\phi(i)$ instead of $\phi(i)/S$ with only a trivial difference.
